# Core data - NSFetchrequest fetching twice the actual count of data

Tags: ios, core-data

NSFetchRequest in the below code is fetching in multiples times count of the data.. Example I have 3 as array count 1st time the method is called, next time it become 6 next 9 and so on. But in the database, the count remains as 3. Why is this happening?

```
// the method is called in viewDidLoad

- (void) create {

[orderList removeAllObjects];
  NSError * error;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrderList"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
for (int addOrd = 0; addOrd < orderMainArray.count; addOrd++) {

    GetOrders *getOrd = (GetOrders*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GetOrders" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    OrderList *ordList = (OrderList*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrderList" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];



    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderId contains[cd] %@", [[orderMainArray objectAtIndex:addOrd] objectForKey:@"orderId"]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

      NSLog(@"\n \n \n count for same data = %d", [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]);

    if ([context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] ==0 ) {

        // all data is saved here 

        [getOrd addOrderListObject:ordList];
        if ([context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"The save was successful! %@", ordList.orderId);

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"The save wasn't successful: %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
        }
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest1 setEntity:entity];

    orderList = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:&error] mutableCopy]; // array count increases every time the method is called 


}
```

Comment: Each time you call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:InManagedObjectContext:` you are creating and adding new objects...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wain - Thanks wain... Could you please answer the same? I would like to mark it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time I call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:InManagedObjectContext:` I was creating and adding new objects. So changed that and now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code mixes fetch requests and inserts of new managed objects.
You insert one OrderList NSManagedObject and one GetOrder NSManagedObject in each iteration of the for-loop. Given your description, I would assume that orderMainArray.count has a value of 3.